# Converting a setup.py Python project to binary with PyInstaller?

Tags: python, setuptools, pyinstaller, package-managers, distribute

I have a project that is described using the standard `setup.py` setup, with some `.py` files that are intended to be executable (in the `scripts=` part of the package) and some `.py` files that are just libraries imported by these script files.

Is there a way to convert this setup to a series of binaries with PyInstaller, such that each of the files that are described by `setup.py` to be scripts are made into executables? The rest of the `.py` are internal libraries so of course those would not need to be converted and would have no use once the binaries are made.

To clarify, I'm only interested in making Mac OS X and Linux binaries, not Windows. thanks.

Comment: Did you ever get to the bottom of it? In my case I just need linux 64-bit binary. I had written a custom script to do the build from hudson and push it to repository. But it would be great if something that integrates with setup.py exists or if someone has attempted to do such an integration. Cheers